# Excel: How to filter values in a pivot table so only rows with the latest date display

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some data I collect and I use a pivot table to analyze it. I recently started collecting the data in a different way to capture a running total, but it's messed up all my pivot tables. I am looking for a way to tame my data.

Here is what I am capturing:

```
Title, Score, Votes
A      41.5     11
```

In the past, I would update the spreadsheet if a title got more votes and the score changed. But then I realized, it would be better if I added a date, copied the row, and then updated the score.

So this:

```
Data, Title, Score, Votes
1/2    A     41.5     11
1/3    A     40.0      9
1/4    A     40.8     10
```

So now I have a vote/score history for each title.

This works good for values that only go up. For example, Date or Views (not shown in example). I can summarize these fields by Max and always get the latest value.

But my problem is that if I want to create a pivot table to see the latest scores and votes for all my titles, there is no way that I can see to do this because sometimes Scores and Votes go down. So this means that even if I summarize values by MAX value, I get an inaccurate report.

So I would get something like this:

```
Title, Date (Max), Score (Max), Votes (Max)  
A      1/4         41.5           11
```

What I am after is a way to show data in a report that only shows values from the most recent date. I am new to Excel and have been teaching myself, so I apologize if there is an obvious solution. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new column to your data showing whether actual row is the latest date of the given title.

`=max(if(b2=b:b,a:a,""))=a2` (supposing that your original data is in columns A-D and you put your first formula in E2) This is an array formula, so you need to hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER after you've typed it.

Now just add the new column as filter in your pivot and filter for `TRUE`.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. I tried this out in a sample workbook and think I understand. I hope I can translate the formula to my production spreadsheet. I think what's happening here is the title column is being compared to the date column, and the max date gets linked to the title? So it tells me the last time a title was updated = true? I should be able to pull this off. Thanks so much @Máté Juhász